# Weyl's asymptotic law for eigenvalues - Rectangle $D = \{0 < x < a, 0 < y < b \}$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

Let the domain $D = \{0 < x < a, 0 < y < b \}$ in the plane. We now that $$\lambda_{n,m} = \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{a^2}+\frac{m^2 \pi^2}{b^2}$$ with the eigenfunction $$u_{n,m}= \sin(\frac{nπ}{a}x) \sin(\frac{mπ}{b}y).$$ I would like to show the Weyl's asymptotic law for eigenvalues, i.e., $\lim_{l \to \infty} \frac{\lambda_l}{l}=\frac{4 \pi}{A}$ ($2$-dimensional), where $A$ is the area of the rectangle. I am blocked on this problem for a while. Is there anyone could give the principle steps how could realize this problem?

Comment: There is probably a typo in the domain definition: $0 < y < y.$

Comment: If your $\lambda_l$ means: the number of pairs $(n,m)$ such that $\lambda_{n,m} < l$. To leading order this is given by the area of the ellipse bounded by $x^2 / a^2 + y^2/b^2 = l / \pi^2$. // Also, if this is the case, you copied Weyl's law wrong: the RHS should be $A / 4\pi$.

Comment: Note also that you should only count $n,m$ such that $n \geq 0$ and $m\geq 0$, since $n$ and $-n$ correspond to essentially the same eigenfunction.

Comment: @WillieWong  No, I am not wrong for $\lim_{l \to \infty} \frac{\lambda_l}{l}=\frac{4 \pi}{A}$; see page $322$ of https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/partial-differential-equations.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The notation can also be interpreted as follows: order the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le \ldots$. Consider $\lambda_N$ for a large $N$, and now follow Willie's outline to approximately determine $N$: The number of smaller eigenvalues is one fourth the number of lattice points in the ellipse
$$
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = \lambda_N/\pi^2 ,
$$
and this is approximately one fourth times the area $= (1/4)\pi ab\lambda_N/\pi^2=A\lambda_N/(4\pi)$. So $N\simeq \lambda_N A/(4\pi)$, as claimed.